# How do I get the i value in app.ts from let i =index ( from html) ? #angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having an array of objects, and I want to make a table for each element from array, so in each table, I have a column for property name and one for property value. I'm using a for , to create tables, and a let i = index. How can i get the i or the index value back in app.ts? I want to get keys and values for each iteration .

Comment: In which case do you want this index, do you want to use a method ? Something linked to the template or not ?

Comment: First of all I'm entry level in Angular. So, i need this index, cause I have a response from a server, in this response i have an array of objects and i need to get the keys and values. Lets asume array is the response, I cant get Object.keys(array) -> i need to pass array[0], then [1] and so on. When I make the table in html page, i use let i = index, and for index =0 i have the first table with Object.keys(array[0] and Object.values(array[0])) but i cant go to next loop, i need something to get the "i" back in app.ts to make Object.values(array[1]) and so on ...

Comment: Ok I see, but then the result of Object.values(array[0]) etc..., where do you need them, in your html or in your ts. Are you able to create a stackblitz with your issue ?

Comment: Yes, i can create a stackblitz, then i send you the link here?

Comment: Yes with a comment or event better you can edit your post to add it, this way if someone else come to your issue he can help you too